# How do I protect against getJSON not calling the callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Before submitting a form button, I make a $.getJSON call that validates some of the data, and when it comes back, it either displays a "you didn't fill out this form correctly" dialog or it does the form.submit().  But sometimes, especially on my slow test server, it takes a few seconds before the callback is called, and so I'd like to put up some visual indication (disabled buttons, wait cursors, etc) that you have pressed the button, and then turning off that visual indication in the callback.  But I'm told that there is a small but non-zero chance that the callback might not be called.

What is the best practice to make sure that in that situation, I don't end up with a non-functional form?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery 1.4. (Mostly.  Some of our pages still use 1.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with an `.error` callback in addition to the `.success` callback instead of `$.getJSON`. If the request fails, the `.error` callback will fire. You can use that to re-enable and display a suitable message, similar to the one shown on StackOverflow when a vote fails. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(html){
     $form.submit();
  },
  error: function(xhr, error){
     console.debug(xhr); 
     console.debug(error);
     $form.find(":input").attr("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: I promote this method. There's also a timeout option you can set for the request so that it calls the error callback whenever it takes longer then x seconds which is why the `setTimeout`-method above is redundant.

Comment: could you add another solution involving [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) and a global error callback. I'd do it myself, but I feel this answer is already adequate enough so no need for me to *compete* with a third answer, nor do I want to edit your answer without your consent ;)

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall - Be my guest, edit away. There's really no need for my consent, but I do appreciate your politeness :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd simply use a timeout. Make sure that enableForm() just returns if the form is already enabled and clear the timeout when the form is disabled to avoid more than one timer running.

setTimeout(enableForm, 10000); // enables form in any case after 10s

Answer (score 2):

You can look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ in The jqXHR Object section, it explains that the function $.getJSON() returns an jqXHR Object that implements  XMLHTTPRequest so you will have available .error, .success and .complete

I think this will work in your case :

```
$.getJSON("a.json", function() {}).error(function() {})
```

Comment: In principle, the same as what I posted, but more concise and *newer*. +1

Comment: That's jQuery 1.5, though, isn't it?

Comment: @Paul, yes it is! However you can use `$.ajaxSetup` to set yourself up with a global error callback handler.

Comment: Sorry, the version was specified after i posted the answer, i checked jquery 1.3 code and the $.ajax function returns undefined, since getJSON its just an specific call to that function, it won't work